# Join With the Resultant list in linq

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have one var variable which is having a single column and i want to make join that column with the database table.my code is as follows :

```
var notlinked = _client.Except(linked).ToList();
var result = (from e in iEnt.clientmasters 
              join g in notlinked on e.ClientID equals g.ClientID 
              select e).ToList();
```

now notlinked is having a single column and depend on that i want to retrieve information from database so in the next line i am doing join to that table but when i execute it getting following error :

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

suggest me some solution to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample application to find things. I have taken two list Customer and another is int list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {


            List customers=new List();
            customers.Add(new Customer(1,"Jalpesh"));
            customers.Add(new Customer(2, "Kaushal"));
            customers.Add(new Customer(3, "Mahesh"));

            List intList=new List{1,2};


            var customerList = customers.Where(c => intList.Contains(c.Id));

        }


    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Customer(int id,string name) {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Linq to Sql that much, but I guess the preoblem is that you are trying to do a join between something coming from the database and something which is a list in memory. You should do something like this:

```
var result = 
    from e in iEnt.clientmasters 
    where notlinked.Contains(e.ClientID)
    select e
```

In this case I think Linq to Sql should be able to generate a SQL IN(...) clause. Not tested at all, but you get the idea.

**EDIT**

For more background look for example [here](http://wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/)

Comment: I edited the answer to give you a more extended reference, Linq to Sql is supposed to support that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the join and rather just write your own output from the LINQ

```
var notlinked = _client.Except(linked).ToList();
var result = (from e in iEnt.clientmasters 
              from g in notlinked 
              where e.ClientID == g.ClientID 
              select new 
              {
                  Colomn1 = e.firstColomn
                  Colomn2 = g.secondColomn
              }).ToList();
```

It's not the most elegant of ways but i tend to do it when every other idea fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<int> notlinked` instead of `var notlinked`. and rather JOIN use WHERE clause and check `notlinked` contains `e.ClientID`

```
List<int> notlinked = _client.Except(linked).Select(o => o.ClientID).ToList<int>();
var result = (from e in iEnt.clientmasters 
              where notlinked.Contains(e.ClientID)
              select e).ToList();
```